# Is it possible to change the version of System.Runtime in a Xamarin project?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've built a DLL of a NetStandard library which is used to access a database. The issue is that after referencing the DLL in my Xamarin Forms project, I cannot use any functions in my library because, the `System.Runtime` is outdated. Is there any way I can update the `System.Runtime` assembly in the project?

[image]

Comment: When I correctly understand the error message, you need o rebuild your application with the new library. It may be necessary to remove the library from and add it anew with the new version, to refresh linking informations.

Comment: @Julo I have done countless rebuilds to no avail

Comment: Did you try to remove the link to library from project and add it anew? When this message remains even after removing and adding new link, this probably mean, that the library you are adding to project is the old version, but the library get somehow changed during the publication/usage progress. I had this message only on standard Windows application and therefore I can not tell for sure what is the problem in Xamarin, but it might be necessary to make a update in building tools.

Comment: @Julo I tried this and it still didn't work. Thank for the advice though.

Comment: Make sure you delete your bin and object directories in your project and rebuild, also try an new project to make sure its not a build thing, xamarin can be a bit flakey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the `*.csproj` file of the `BucketList.Api` and change the line:

```
<Reference Include="System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, publicKeyToken=b04f5f711d50a3a">
```

to:

```
<Reference Include="System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, publicKeyToken=b04f5f711d50a3a">
```

Recompile the `BucketList.Api` DLL and reference that.

Alternatively you may try this, which may or may not be legit:

```
<Reference Include="System.Runtime">
```